# SQL deadlocked exception

Tags: c#, sql

Using C# I wrote a windows service and seperate windows application

For some reason i keep receiving the below error.

It was running fine for a long time now this error occurs.

> "SQL Exception During CustomSQL Execute: Transaction (Process ID 119)
>   was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been
>   chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. "

I know other services are also accessing the same table in the database. They have been for a long while i.e. months and never seen this error.

How can I troubleshoot the error to find precisely what is causing this error?

Thank you

Comment: Do one of your other statements have a dangling transaction they forgot to commit/rollback?

Comment: Set up a database profiler that logs the deadlock - then you can see which processes are conflicting and that way debug back into your code

Comment: Make sure that if more than one proc/statement is accessing the same tables, that they are joined in the same order. Also, you can use "with nolock" in the join if you are not too worried about data being changed in another statement. As Allan said, the only way I know to catch it is with the profiler but if it doesn't happen often, it might not catch it!

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to troubleshoot deadlocks. Usually i start by running this query:

```
Declare @xml xml

Select @xml = CAST(target_data AS XML) 
FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
    Inner Join sys.dm_xe_sessions s ON s.address = st.event_session_address
WHERE [name] = 'system_health'

Select
    XEventData.XEvent.value('@package', 'nvarchar(max)') Package,
    XEventData.XEvent.value('@name', 'varchar(max)') Name,
    XEventData.XEvent.value('@timestamp', 'DateTime') Date,
    XEventData.XEvent.query('(data/value)[1]') Deadlock,
    cast(XEventData.XEvent.value ('(data/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as xml),
    XEvent.query('.') --*
From @xml.nodes('//RingBufferTarget/event') as XEventData (XEvent)
WHERE XEventData.XEvent.value('@name', 'varchar(4000)') = 'xml_deadlock_report';
```

You then can use results to see the reason of deadlock.

Comment: error: Invalid object name 'sys.dm_xe_session_targets'.

Comment: @CaughtInALoop what version of sql server? this should work on sql server 2008 R2 and newer.

Comment: ahh its version 2005  in sql server 2008 error:    Invalid object name 'sys.dm_xe_session_targets'.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you might need to check to reduce the chances of a deadlock:

1. Minimize the size of transaction and transaction times.
2. Always access server objects in the same order each time in application.
3. Avoid cursors, while loops, or process which requires user input
   while it is running.
4. Reduce lock time in application.
5. Use query hints to prevent locking if possible (NoLock, RowLock)
6. Select deadlock victim by using SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY.